Flutter Build: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
every time i try to build my app i get this error
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_native_image:verifyReleaseResources'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
> Android resource linking failed
ERROR:G:\shakawa\system\build\flutter_native_image\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:194: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           18.5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1


this is my flutter doctor
flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4894], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at G:\Flutter files\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2663184aa7 (12 days ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
    • Engine revision 36335019a8
    • Dart version 3.5.3
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\yosf3\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: G:\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11609105)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at G:\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11609105)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4894]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 129.0.6668.59
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 129.0.2792.52

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.


Gradle is telling you the answer. In the failure output you pasted, this line has the important piece.
"G:\shakawa\system\build\flutter_native_image\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:194: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found."
Specifically the resource of android:attr/lStar not found is not found. This looks to be a failure in the flutter_native_image package. Unfortunately it looks like this project is discontinued.
If you are looking to resize images you can check out this website as a potential option.
